# Smarty tokens in postal mailing labels?

Tags: smarty, address-labels

Total newbie here, but am I correct in my understanding that Smarty tokens do not function in the postal mailing label template? I have them enabled and can see them working in email and PDF letters, but no luck with mailing labels. Presumably mailing labels are not passed through the Smarty templater code.

I am trying to solve the oft discussed problem of trying to produce mailing labels formatted correctly for a variety of different countries in a mailing list and was hoping that using Smarty conditionals might be a simple solution, but I guess not.

Comment: I am looking for info on mailing labels and modifying them too. Anyone have guidance on this?

Comment: Sorry, Sheila, but as near as I can tell Smarty conditionals do not function in the postal mailing labels and there is little option for customizing them. I solved my problem by exporting the fields in csv format to LibreOffice Calc (because Excel seems unable to handle non-English characters) and then using some VBA (Visual Basic) code to massage the fields into the proper orders for the different countries and then fed the output into MSWord mailing label templates. We subsequently started using a mailing service that simply wanted a csv file with the fields to feed into their own software.